# NLP How to get the difference between 2 documents

Tags: nlp, scikit-learn, stanford-nlp, gensim, spacy

I have 2 documents A-B (or 2 series of documents), and would like to get the 
a new document showing difference between the two document: A-B

By difference, there are several definitions, one is :
           List of words/"concept" include in A but not in B.

I am thinking of using TF IDF for each sentence of A and B ,
such as :

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
d1 = [open(f1) for f1 in text_files]
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(d1)
pairwise_similarity = tfidf * tfidf.T
```

I am not sure if this would be relevant to generate a new document C= "A-B",
especially am interested in "semantic difference" in the document C

Comment: I don't think this is a trivial problem that can be quickly answered in a SO post. I would ask in Reddit/machinelearning.

Comment: Ok, sure. Maybe, some references would be useful to start investigating.

Answer (score 0):

gensim calculates the similarity between documents using [Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) (details [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut3.html)):

```
index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(lsi[corpus]) # transform corpus to LSI space and index it
sims = index[vec_lsi] # perform a similarity query against the corpus
```

In the code above, `vec_lsi` is a document A in LSI space, and `sims` is an array of similarities between A and the documents in `corpus`.

As per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Angular_distance_and_similarity), you can turn cosine similarity around and compute angular distance, which is a distance metric:

```
distance = np.arccos(sims)/np.pi
```

Note that these cosine similarity and angular distance are vector-based and their interpretation will depend on what your vectors consist of. In my example, the vectors are Latent Semantic Indexing (LSI) scores, so angular distance is related to distance in semantic space.

Comment: But, it does not provide anything to generate the document C= A-B